# Metaphone vs Levenshtein vs Soundex vs Hamming

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fuzzy-search

I want to implement a `Fuzzy Search` using php 7 and MySQL 5.7. I made some searches in Google and I found these algorithms are used for this purpose: Metaphone, Levenshtein, Soundex and Hamming.

I want to `search for song titles` in my table. So the user can search using title, artists names or both of them **with misspelling** also, like YouTube for ex.

What is the best algorithm to use for this purpose and how can be implemented in php/MySQL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOUNDEX() is a simple algorithm from the early twentieth century tuned to help look up proper names in American English. It was built for Bell System directory-assistance operators. It's designed to generate lots of false positives, from which a human can pick likely hits. It's probably unsuitable for your purpose because your words are not mostly proper names.

Metaphone and double metaphone are refinements on SOUNDEX. They work on a wider variety of words.

These work best word-by-word, rather than on phrases like song names. If you implement any of these you'll need to implement the word-by-word matching and some kind of scoring scheme  The good news is that these are suitable for indexing, and work based on the sounds of the words.

Levenshtein distance works on words or phrases, and works on spelling rather than sounds. It's not suitable for indexed search, because these distances work pair wise. In my experience it's tricky to score Levenshtein distances, because longer phrases have many more ways to differ from other long phrases than do short ones.

Before you dive into trying to build fuzzy search using these raw algorithms, you might try MySQL FULLTEXT search and Sphinx. Both these technologies handle phrase scoring and stop words decently well. Sphinx also has some suppport for synonym tables, which helps handle common misspelling.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So you are saying that none of them are suitable?  Im using full text search but it has no support for misspelling should i go with Sphinx?