# Use Soundex search with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement Soundex searching in EF Core, I have written this LINQ that should query a table called 'Customers' by first and last name.

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
//More code
customers = hisDb.Customers.Where(p => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(p.Fname.Trim()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(FName.Trim()) && SqlFunctions.SoundCode(p.Lname.Trim()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(LName.Trim())).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

However, I am getting this error.

> System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.SoundCode(String arg)

Anyway getting Soundex search to work with EF Core 6?

Comment: On which database engine ?

Comment: I am using SQL Server, I added a tag.

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer` is the wrong namespace. I suspect you added a reference to EF 6.2, not EF Core 6. EF Core 6 [doesn't have SoundCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-7.0). Probably because SOUNDEX is so product-specific and so limited there's little reason to add it to EF itself. You can use `FromSql` to include it, or [map the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping)

Comment: The project is using EF Core, is it possible to use both?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Implement fuzzy matching search? There are far better algorithms than SOUNDEX like the Damerau-Levenshtein distance. SOUNDEX only works for US names.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Open to any suggestions.

Comment: To solve which problem? It matters. Are you trying to lookup names for example? SQL Server offers no indexes that could speed up fuzzy searches. Even the Full Text Search indexes can be used to find words in text, not find names that differ by 1-2 characters. That kind of search is provided by products like Elastic or OpenSearch.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378158/metaphone-vs-levenshtein-vs-soundex-vs-hamming/37379279#37379279) might be worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SO [allows](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) a user to answer his own question. I have found this solution, but I do not know how **EF Core** friendly is.

In `DbContext`, I added

```
[DbFunction(Name = "SoundEx", IsBuiltIn = true]
    public static string SoundEx(string input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

and called it in my code

`customers = hisDb.Customers.Where(p => DbContext.SoundEx(p.Fname.Trim()) == DbContext.SoundEx(FName.Trim()) && DbContext.SoundEx(p.Lname.Trim()) == DbContext.SoundEx(LName.Trim())).ToList();`

Comment: I would consider the suggestion of creating a precalculated Soundex column and then just looking up a match to allow indexing if you can and your data is of any significant size.

Comment: @NetMage If you have a solution please post it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is pre-calculate the Soundex-values for all of your Customers' first names, and store (and index) those values in your database. Then query against those values using the Soundex-value of you search argument.

For instance

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD FirstNameSoundex AS SOUNDEX(FirstName);

CREATE INDEX Customers_FirstName_Soundex ON Customers (FirstNameSoundex);
```

Update the DbContext to add this new computed column and query

```
var soundCode = SqlFunctions.SoundCode(arg);
hisDb.Customers.Where(cust => cust.FirstNameSoundex == soundCode)
```

This way you won't have to scan and SOUNDEX() the entire table at every query, and the database doesn't have to know about your particular SqlFunction.

(disclaimer: I don't know if SqlFunctions.SoundCode is in fact the same as T-SQL SOUNDEX() but if so, the above should be fine)

Comment: There's no `SqlFunctions.SoundCode` at all. That's what the question is about

Comment: Altering the database is not in my authority

Comment: Ok, well you're going to see atrocious performance on that query once you reach and kind of volume - both in terms of data and number of queries, so eventually your DBA will see things your way. If it is because the database is third-party, you can define the soundex columns in a view and index/query that in stead.